# Display in website rows from table

Tags: c#, sql, database, namespaces

I have created a local database in Visual Studio 2010 and a web application which interacts with it. I want to create a search function in order to obtain some rows from a table. I have a text field where i write a date (delivery date for a product, for example) and a button. On clicking the button, i want to bring on my web page information about an invoice. Please, check out my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=JOHN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=subiect1;Integrated Security=True");
try
{
    con.Open();
    DataSet datas = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Factura where Data_Livrare = @Data_Livrare", con);
    SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
    commandBuilder.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Data_Livrare", (object)txtData.Text));
    SqlDataReader reader = reader.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {                   
        adapter.Fill(datas);
    }                
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Label3.Text = "Error --> " + ex.Message;
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

I get the error:

> "A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces;
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand is a type, not a namespace".

If i delete the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand directive, i get plenty of errors referring to some methods which are, apparently, undefined (such as Parameters from `commandBuilder.Parameters.Add` and `ExecuteReader()`). When i run the program in browser, complete the textfield and click the button, i get:

> " Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized."

What am i missing here? Is it only the user directive wrong or i simply don't approach well this problem?

I must mention I am a beginner in C#.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry, John! I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 2):

Check your `using` clauses at the top of your code.

I think you have `using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;`

You should have `System.Data.SqlClient;`

If you check the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will see that the namespace for `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` is `System.Data.SqlClient`